# Accessing file in restricted directory

Tags: acl

As an experiment I tried, and failed, to print a file in another user's Documents directory. The accessing user (admin) has read permission on the file however they have no permissions on its parent directory (the 'Documents' directory of the other user).

```
~ wsee$ ls -le
drwx------@ 32 wsee  staff       1024 10 Feb 11:51 Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
....
~ wsee$ cd Documents
Documents wsee$ ls -le
-rw-r--r--   1 wsee  staff         12 10 Feb 11:00 test
```

```
~ admin$ cat /Users/wsee/Documents/test
cat: /Users/wsee/Documents/test: Permission denied
```

I wondered whether I might be able to access the file because I knew its path, please could someone explain why this wasn't the case and what stopped me from accessing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access a file, you need permission to access every part of its path: that is, every directory the file is contained in, and the file itself. Simply granting access to the file is not enough if you're not allowed to access one of its parent directories. This behavior is the same across all UNIXes (as far as I know).

Answer (score 3):

Permission was denied to access the `Documents` directory. You could have entered the command below and received the same results.

```
~ admin$ cat /Users/wsee/Documents/does_not_exist
cat: /Users/wsee/Documents/does_not_exist: Permission denied
```

Adding `sudo` would allow access to the `Documents` directory and would then change the error message, as shown below.

```
~ admin$ sudo cat /Users/wsee/Documents/does_not_exist
Password:
cat: /Users/wsee/Documents/does_not_exist: No such file or directory
```

Where as the command below would print the `test` file.

```
~ admin$ sudo cat /Users/wsee/Documents/test
```